# Trying to add a value in the second row of a table

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update, where-clause

I am trying to add a specific value to a cell of the second row of a feature-class-table. Doesn't work with my code:

```
    #First row
    rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(tb_value)
    row = rows.newRow()
    rows.insertRow(row)

    cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(tb_value)
    for row in cur:
        row.setValue(fn_value_object, COUNTER)
        row.setValue(fn_name_area, gebietsname)
        row.setValue(fn_name_object, objektname)
        cur.updateRow(row)

    #Second row
    whereClause = """{0} = 2"""
    whereClause = whereClause.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(tb_value, "Rowid"))
    cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(tb_value, whereClause)
    row = rows.newRow()
    rows.insertRow(row)
    for row in cur:
        row.setValue(fn_value_object, COUNTER2)
```

I tried it with a where-clause, but the value which is set in the second row is 0.

Comment: Why aren't you using an arcpy.da.InsertCursor and arcpy.da.UpdateCursor? It looks like you're not updating the row that you've changed with cur.updateRow(row) so it's not being stored. Look at the examples https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000008n000000

Comment: not checked, but I think that you are missing the flush of memory (del cur). Note that a better practice would be to use "with ... as cur :" so you make sure that the memory is cleaned. also, it is better to use arcpy.da cursor and, finally, I don't get why you insert rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertcursor is for inserting new rows, not updating values of existing rows (it is a bit unclear what you are asking). You are using old cursor, switch to [data access cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) instead:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\somefeatureclassortable'
field_to_update = 'somefieldname'
row_id_field = 'Rowid'
value = 123 #Or '123' if string and you will have to modify sql query

sql = """{0}=2""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc, field=row_id_field))
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field_to_update,sql) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=value
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works very well! The reason why I am inserting a new row, is because the table is just created in my script. So it's a new table without any rows. So my idea was to add rows and then update the default values.